# How to increase length of linestring using Jts functions

Tags: distance, linestring, jts-topology-suite

lf l get a line string having a legth lesser than expected then l need to project or extend that line further in such a way that it meets minimum length requirement.

For e.g.

l have 2 coordinates A(ax,ay) and B(bx,by) and distance between (A,B) is 0.5 meter and minimum length should be 1 meter then coordinate B should be shifted/extended in such a way that distance between them is 1 meter.
l was trying to achieve this using gauss krueger but doesn't seem to be working. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are working on a Cartesian Plane (and if you are not then JTS can't help, so reproject) the following should do what you want. It is basically some trigonometry to get the gradient of the line and then calculate where the end should be.

```
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.LineString;

public class LineExtender {
  static GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int SIZE = 16;
    Coordinate p1 = new Coordinate(1, 1);
    double delta = .5;
    for (float i = 0; i < 360; i += (360.0 / SIZE)) {
      double angle = Math.toRadians(i);
      Coordinate p2 = new Coordinate(p1.x + (delta * Math.sin(angle)), p1.y + (delta * Math.cos(angle)));
      LineString line = gf.createLineString(new Coordinate[] { p1, p2 });
      LineExtender me = new LineExtender();
      LineString line2 = me.checkLine(line);
      System.out.println(line+"\n"+line2);
    }
  }

  private LineString checkLine(LineString line) {
    LineString ret = line;
    double target = 1;
    double length = line.getLength();
    if (length < target) {
      // extend line
      double delta = target - length;
      Coordinate c1 = line.getStartPoint().getCoordinate();
      Coordinate c2 = line.getEndPoint().getCoordinate();
      double angle = Math.atan2((c2.x - c1.x), (c2.y - c1.y));
      Coordinate c3 = new Coordinate(c2.x + (delta * Math.sin(angle)), c2.y + (delta * Math.cos(angle)));
      ret = gf.createLineString(new Coordinate[] { c1, c2, c3 });
    }
    return ret;
  }
}
```

I left the original points in the new line (it made debugging easier) but you could leave it out by making the line using:

```
ret = gf.createLineString(new Coordinate[] { c1, c3 });
```